# Backbone collection fetch doesnt update @collection.length

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, coffeescript

I fetch the first 15 records of a collection and after clicking on a button I fetch another 15 records for the same collection. After the 2nd time the length of the collection is 15 and not 30. Even though 15 new records are being loaded and the 'add' event works perfectly.

Code for the 1st time:

```
@collection.fetch
  data: @filter
  update: true
  success: =>
    @onSuccessCollection()
```

Code for the 2nd time:

```
loadMore: ->
  @filter.skip = @collection.length
  @collection.fetch
    update: true
    data: @filter,
    success: =>
      @onSuccessCollection()
```

success callback(returns 15 first time and 15 second time while 30 is expected):

```
onSuccessCollection: ->
  console.log 'onCollectionReset: collection.length: ', @collection.length
```

I use Backbone 0.9.10

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll have to set the flag `remove` to false. The "smart update" has the remove flag default to true, so when you're only fetching 15 models, your 15 first are removed (hence the length equals to 15):

```
// Smartly update a collection with a change set of models, adding,
// removing, and merging as necessary.
update: function(models, options) {
  options = _.extend({add: true, merge: true, remove: true}, options);
```

[Source](https://github.com/documentcloud/backbone/blob/0.9.10/backbone.js)

Comment: Seriously that easy... Thanks a lot mate! Works perfectly.

Comment: @MichaelKoper the hard part is to get the doc from an older version :)

Comment: @MichaelKoper sure, but the change logs may sometimes avoid you this pain still ;)